# Fire Tablet FreeTime sometimes takes a long time to start an app

Tags: amazon-kindle-fire

Once every few days when my kids go into their account (FreeTime), none of the apps work right away. You'll tap/click to start running a game and the icon turns this like teal color, it waits a minute or two then it appears to either download or install something because a yellow progress bar shows up under the icon. It does this *for every single app*. The download/install process seems to queue, too.

If I go in directly into an adult's profile, this never happens (even while it is "downloading" in the kids profile). All apps work immediately.

Why does it do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Referring to [a similar case posted on Amazon forum](https://www.amazon.com/gp/help/customer/forums/kindleqna/ref=cs_hc_k_tv?ie=UTF8&forumID=Fx1FI6JDSFEQQ7V&cdThread=TxTWQ5VN4AYU7W), this happens when the device has low storage.

First, [check the device's storage](https://www.amazon.com/gp/help/customer/forums/kindleqna/ref=cs_hc_k_pl?ie=UTF8&forumID=Fx1FI6JDSFEQQ7V&cdThread=TxTWQ5VN4AYU7W&cdPage=1&cdMsgId=Mx14NFA4T6IQSWN#Mx14NFA4T6IQSWN)

> To access your "Storage" on the kindle follow these steps:
>
> 1. Swipe down from the top
> 2. Click on Settings
> 3. Device Options
> 4. Click on Storage
>
> From there you can see how much storage you have left and how much storage your books/games/apps etc are using.

Next, [remove corrupted download](https://www.amazon.com/gp/help/customer/forums/kindleqna/ref=cs_hc_k_pl?ie=UTF8&forumID=Fx1FI6JDSFEQQ7V&cdThread=TxTWQ5VN4AYU7W&cdPage=1&cdMsgId=MxD3HU2XAVPIK3#MxD3HU2XAVPIK3),

> It sounds like it might have been a corrupt download. Please try long pressing on the icon and "Remove from Device" then do another hard restart. But this time, please hold the power button down for 40 seconds (regardless of when the screen goes black.) Then try to redownload the application.

If it doesn't work, then [try to free up some space](https://www.amazon.com/gp/help/customer/forums/kindleqna/ref=cs_hc_k_pl?ie=UTF8&forumID=Fx1FI6JDSFEQQ7V&cdThread=TxTWQ5VN4AYU7W&cdPage=1&cdMsgId=Mx23GIAQ25PFOCS#Mx23GIAQ25PFOCS),

> I had the same issue with my daughter's fire and I think it is related to storage. It's almost as if the app doesn't have enough room to download so it fails, but it never provides a message that there is a storage problem. One of the previous suggestions was to select "Remove from Device" and do a hard restart, but that is not an option (only "Remove from Carousel") which leads me to believe that it does not fully download. A hard restart also did nothing to help. I removed the app from the carousel, then removed a bunch of apps, and restarted. The problem was resolved. Now whenever her Fire starts acting glitchy I reduce her apps and make sure she has plenty of storage.

Or alternate method to [clear FreeTime's apps data](https://www.amazon.com/gp/help/customer/forums/kindleqna/ref=cs_hc_k_pl?ie=UTF8&forumID=Fx1FI6JDSFEQQ7V&cdThread=TxTWQ5VN4AYU7W&cdPage=2&cdMsgId=Mx1PHZ14G7Q6PX6#Mx1PHZ14G7Q6PX6)

> 1. From your kid's freetime account pull down from the top of the screen. Choose "settings" (you will have to have the password to move on)
> 2. Choose "storage" from the options listed
> 3. Choose apps, from the list
> 4. Select All (button or choosing each app checkbox individually)
> 5. At the bottom, click the "remove" button. This clears the stored version of the app data (and possibly the app itself). It does NOT delete the app from your Amazon account or cloud.
> 6. Back out of all the settings and go back to the apps page (where your child would start the app they want to play.)
>      While you have internet access, click on any (or all) of the apps one at a time to download a new clean version of the app from the cloud.